# How to improve Performance with isTextPresent() equivalent function in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have implemented data driven framework and so my isTextPresent function might have dynamic values.  Also, I need to have a lot of assert texts in my application.  I tried using xpath like

`boolean b=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(.,stringc3)]")).getText().contains(stringc3);`

where stringc3 is the text to be checked.  But this implementation is taking a very long time(with webdriverbackedselenium, my tests used to take around 3 mins but with webdriver and above code, it takes around 20mins).  So is there a way to make this test run faster?

I came to know that these functions are now supported for exports from selenium ide(http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/detail?r=17718)

So, is there any plan to implement isTextPresent function in webdriver?

Comment: The first issue is that you are not being direct in your XPath query. Regardless of how you do it, you are using `*` in your query, so the XPath engine will go off and search every single element in the entire page. Second, I'm not sure why you are checking the text twice? You check it once in the XPath, and again in code. Why? Third, do you have any timeouts implemented? Selenium will wait the entire length of these timeouts. Fourth, have you tried using other drivers? Is it slow on particular drivers?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  For your questions, since mine is a data driven framework, I cannot define the xpath without '*', because the text might appear any where(inside/outside a table/s).  For second, my code catches issues only if I check the text twice.  Other wise, it passes them without shouting for error.  For third, I have given timeout of 30 secs and it is working fine.  I dont think, it is an issue with time out.  For fourth question, I havent tried using other drivers.

Comment: "For second, my code catches issues only if I check the text twice. Other wise, it passes them without shouting for error." ...There is something very wrong here...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `isTextPresent` is nothing but inner text from `body` tag. So you can grab all the text from the page first and then find the string you need.

```
string alltext = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText();
```

Comment: My webpage is a big one and the body text will also be very big.  Also, I have implemented the other way. My code reads through an excel file and as and when assert for text is present, I check for that text in the web page.

Comment: @SuchitraR.D actually I don't see a big problem with very big body text. If you have several text assertions in one test case it will be faster to find `body` tag once and go through its text instead of finding the xpath locators each time.